# Using R lm function in Python on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, r, pandas, lm

I would like to use the **R** function **lm** to calculate a linear regression in **Python**. 
My data is in the form of a pandas data frame. Like this small example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d2 = {'V1' : pd.Series([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3]),
     'V2' : pd.Series([2,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,2]),
     'V3' : pd.Series([1.,2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2.]),
     'V4' : pd.Series([1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2])}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I would like to run the R function lm in Python:

```
model = lm(V1~.,data=df2)
```

Calling the function with the **~.** is essential for me, because my real data set is huge and I'd like to use all variables as X variables.

After that, I would like to extract a vector with column names for which the coefficients are **not NA**.

I've read about the rpy2 package, but I am rather a python beginner and some help would be great. All examples I have found so far, just use one X variable and no pandas DataFrame, which is not helpful for me.

Thank you!

Comment: You can try using `subprocess` with `Rscript`. That's what I'm using in order to run R from within Python. I find rpy2 very buggy and inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `pyper`.  Assign the object into `R` environment after creating the connection.  Then apply the `R` functions on the dataset and get the output back with `r.get`

```
from pyper import *
r=R(use_pandas=True) 
r.assign("rdf2", df2)
r('model <- lm(V1~.,data=rdf2)')
r('nm1 <-  names(which(!is.na(coef(model))))[-1]')
out = r.get('nm1')
list(out)
#['V2', 'V3', 'V4']
```

---

Checking the output from `R` side

```
tmp <- read.csv('tmptest.csv')
model <- lm(V1~.,data= tmp)
nm1 <-  names(which(!is.na(coef(model))))[-1]
nm1
#[1] "V2" "V3" "V4"
```

Comment: This seems to be interesting, but I can't install the package pyper. I get this error: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyper  

  How did you install it?

Comment: Try `pip install pyper`.

Comment: @Lisa Have you tried the `pip install` as coffeinjunky mentioned.  I think the OS have some issues with different packages.  e.g. I had hard time in installing rpy2 in mac.  So, I gave up installing rpy2 and installed pyper.